# queue functions calls between servers backed with Redis for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, redis, queue

I want to ensure that each function is called one after the other, between servers instances (or cluster nodes).
i can freely add function to the queue when i need, and those functions are asynch.

It could be backed by Redis, and work on NodeJS.

Please would you know any lib to do that?
or any way to implement?

I tried many jobs queue lib like Kue, but it does not ensure one only call between instances.

Thanks a lot
Seb

Answer (score 0):

i found out how to do it.
For anyone interrested: i used a lock lib with infinity retry.

The lib is node-redlock: https://github.com/mike-marcacci/node-redlock
It implements the latest recommanded way of locking ressources by Redis: http://redis.io/topics/distlock which is more reliable on Clustered Redis infrastructures. There is more implémentations than NodeJS on this page.

The stupid trick to have a polling queue of functions call is to use the locker with Infinity as value for retryCount setting.
Its very easy to wrap this with an object having aquire(callabck) ad release functions to handle it.

If someone has critism againts this solution, and/or othr technique, i would be pleased to ear from.

Thanks